# Element "frameset" is not supported from visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xhtml, frames, frameset

I have a plain html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <frameset rows="*">
        <frame name="inner" src="inner.htm" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

In visual studio 2010 I get warnings "(XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'body' occurs too few times" and "(XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'frameset' is not supported.". However the w3c validator says it is OK. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not a plain html file, by the way. It's an XHTML file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a warning saying "Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional)..." you are testing against XHTML Transitional instead of XHTML Frameset.

Solution: switch the target schema to XHTML Frameset.
When I do so, I get only a single warning: "Attribute 'name' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended."

Comment: Thanks, that was it all right. Normally I have a lot of respect for visual studio, but I have to say that sucks big time. I can't comprehend why it would want to validate all files against a globally configured doctype set as part of the user preferences, rather than validating each file against the doctype specified in the file itself!

(tools/options/text editor/html/validation in case anyone else is looking for the setting)

Comment: Oh... thanks for that. I didn't even know about that checkbox! And it works very nicely too; you can even have it switch between HTML5 and XHTML5 validation for instance. Thanks again.