# How to use frames in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, frames, html-frames

I want to use Frame in asp.net.I want to divide the page in two parts.In the left side some link will be there.By clicking on one link the corresponding the page will display in the right side.While i am trying to do by using frame tag .It is showing " Element 'frame' is not supported." .

Can anyone have any idea how to use frame tag in asp.net?

Comment: Set the proper doctype, see [Element "frameset" is not supported from visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090902/element-frameset-is-not-supported-from-visual-studio-2010). Anyway you don't want to be using frames in 2014.

Comment: Which version of .net are you targeting? If its 2.0 or above then you should use Master Page. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<frameset rows="14%,83%,4%" frameborder="0">
   <frame src="../Common/Header.aspx" frameborder="0" noresize class="pop_col_top">

   <frameset cols="22%,78%" class="pop_col_top"  frameborder="0">
           <frame name="left" src="Setup.aspx" frameborder="0" noresize class="pop_col_top cell_hspace1 frameborder">
           <frame name="myFrm" noresize class="pop_col_top frameborder">
   </frameset>

   <frame src="../Common/Footer.aspx" frameborder="0" noresize class="pop_col_top">
   </frameset>
```

But It's not recommend to use Frames. You can use an IFrame, and load the source document for that IFrame.

Because The Framset is **Deprecated**

Like this

```
<iframe id="frm1" src="http://localhost/NetShopping/Home.aspx" width="1300px"  ></iframe>
```